# jQuery .height() and .outerHeight() returning zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a small jQuery plugin that will vertically center a div based on it's height,

Basically in my css I have `top: 50%`, but since the height is variable I need to calculate this.

The HTML for this looks like

```
<div class="button-wrapper js-center" data-center="vertical" style="margin-top: 0px;"
    <span class="sub-text">Multiline text with two lines</span>
    <a href="" class="shop-btn">Shop_</a>
</div>
```

In my plugin I tried logging the height, but it keeps on returning zero:

```
console.log($el);
console.log("$el.outerHeight(): " + $el.outerHeight());
console.log("$el[0].scrollHeight: " + $el[0].scrollHeight);

// output:
$el.outerHeight(): 0
$el[0].scrollHeight: 0
```

When I use dev tools to check, it looks like this:
[image]

So I'm wondering what potentially could go wrong, for reference, this is the plugin I'm (trying) to write: http://pastebin.com/Qz7BgkcG

EDIT:
This is the main CSS that is used on the `.button-wrapper`

```
.button-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -125px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100; 
}
```

EDIT 2:
Recreated with all css, but I'm not getting the same issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/8Etex/

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6XspB/ look at your css.

Comment: I'm assuming `$el` is set to the `div`?

Comment: This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/QrueC/. Can you show the HTML and your JavaScript?

Comment: Are you calling the "fix" after the document has been fully loaded? Until this point, both width and height can return zero.

Comment: What do you get with `.height()`?

Comment: @KevinB Updated with CSS now

Comment: @praguian correct, $el is referring to the main parent (`.button-wrapper`)

Comment: @MelanciaUK Yes, everything is called after the document has been loaded

Comment: @praguian `.height()` is also returning zero

Comment: @woutr_be I still can't re-create your issue even with your css. http://jsfiddle.net/6XspB/1/ the issue must be elsewhere. Do you get the same results in multiple browsers?

Comment: @woutr_be I can't recreate such an issue, I'm [getting height returned on my div element](http://jsfiddle.net/NkPnX/). Is your code in the `$(document).ready()` function, to ensure things have height assigned at the time you run your check?

Comment: Timing of making call for calculating element height matters. Try using seTimeout approach with 500 to 1000 ms and in that try calculating height of your desired element.

Comment: @woutr_be Can you update your question with your code for how you're defining `$el`?

Comment: @KevinB I just recreated it too, with most of the css that I use, but it seems to work, could it be related to me using animations as well? http://jsfiddle.net/8Etex/

Comment: @praguian All code is executed after $(document).ready(), some elements are added by javascript though

Comment: @Chris `$('.js-center').fullCenter()`, $el is referring to `.js-center`

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the issue is because jQuery's .height() method returns the element's *computed height* rather than the actual box model (ref: [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/height/)).

If I look at the element you've created in the jsFiddle above, you'll see Firefox doesn't recognise a computed height for your absolute-positioned element. This means it will just return zero. If I force a height attribute on the element in CSS for example, the computed dimensions would be updated and I can retrieve a value.

[image: Firefox Debugging Tools]

Comment: That's true, if you set a fixed height, it will always return the correct amount, but the problem is that I'm having lines of text which could be variable, hence why I can't use a pure (cross-browser) CSS solution and have to do it with some little javascript.